# Is it possible to run rm -rf / without root access?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, android-emulator

I see videos of people running `rm -rf /` on their android but they always run it with root access that is running `su` first so I tried doing the same on my unrooted phone by running `rm -r -i /` but then it 'promoted 'examine files in directory /?'  so I got scared because I was not sure whether it will erase my files or not so I would like to know if `rm -rf /` without root  erase OS files and brick my device?

Answer (score 0):

First off, running `rm -rf /` is always a bad idea – but you probably know that already.

Second: Yes, of course you *can* run this even without root. But it wouldn't be able to delete all files, for multiple reasons:

- it can only delete files where the user executing the command has permissions to. Those are, naturally, pretty few (except for on shared storage aka SD card)
- parts of the file system are mounted read-only (eg. `/system`). Those couldn't even be deleted with root powers unless before remounted with write access.

Comment: See my answer. I agree with that *`rm -rf /` is a bad idea*, but not *you can do it only partially*. In fact you **can't do it at all**.

Comment: @iBug I don't plan to try it out, but to my experience it would simply throw a bunch of errors ("permission denied") while still removing everything it has permission to. If you ask "what experience": A script with a missing variable initialisation (`rm -rf ${foo}/*` with `$foo` being empty) on a Linux system. Admitted, the trailing `*` might make a difference here. Whichever answer is the "absolutely right one" (if any): in both cases, OP wouldn't "erase OS files and brick my device" :) And your answer proves you *can* do it – but you get errors :)